# How to increase the size of deconv2d filters for a fixed data size?

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, deconvolution, dcgan

I am trying to adjust this [DCGAN code](https://github.com/carpedm20/DCGAN-tensorflow/blob/master/model.py) to be able to work with 2x80 data samples.

All [generator](https://github.com/carpedm20/DCGAN-tensorflow/blob/master/model.py#L357) layers are `tf.nn.deconv2d` other than h0, which is ReLu. Generator filter sizes per level are currently:

```
Generator: h0: s_h16 x s_w16: 1  x  5
Generator: h1: s_h8 x s_w8: 1  x  10
Generator: h2: s_h4 x s_w4: 1  x  20
Generator: h3: s_h2 x s_w2: 1  x  40
Generator: h4: s_h x s_w: 2  x  80
```

Because of the nature of my data I would like them to be initially generated as 2 x ..., i.e. for filters to be `2 x 5`, `2 x 10`, `2 x 20`, `2 x 40`, and `2 x 80`. However when I just manually enter `s_h16 = 2 * s_h16` and so on up to `s_h2 = 2 * s_h2`, I run into the following error:

```
ValueError: Shapes (64, 1, 40, 64) and (64, 2, 40, 64) are not compatible
```

So I know that the error happens at the level h3, but I can't quite track it down (64 here is the batch size). Any ideas how this can be fixed?

---

**Edit:** the edited DCGANs code is [in this repository](https://github.com/Instassa/DCGAN-tensorflow), after the DCGAN-tensorflow is set-up [as in the instructions](https://github.com/Instassa/DCGAN-tensorflow/blob/master/README.md) you'd have to place Data_npy folder into `DCGAN-tensorflow/data` folder.

Then running `python main.py --dataset Data_npy --input_height=2 --output_height=2 --train` would provide you with the error I get.

The full error traceback looks as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/marija/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py", line 560, in merge_with
    new_dims.append(dim.merge_with(other[i]))
  File "/home/marija/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py", line 135, in merge_with
    self.assert_is_compatible_with(other)
  File "/home/marija/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py", line 108, in assert_is_compatible_with
    % (self, other))
ValueError: Dimensions 1 and 2 are not compatible

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 97, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/home/marija/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "main.py", line 80, in main
    dcgan.train(FLAGS)
  File "/home/marija/DCGAN-tensorflow/model.py", line 180, in train
    .minimize(self.g_loss, var_list=self.g_vars)
  File "/home/marija/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py", line 315, in minimize
    grad_loss=grad_loss)
  File "/home/marija/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py", line 386, in compute_gradients
    colocate_gradients_with_ops=colocate_gradients_with_ops)
  File "/home/marija/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py", line 580, in gradients
    in_grad.set_shape(t_in.get_shape())
  File "/home/marija/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 413, in set_shape
    self._shape = self._shape.merge_with(shape)
  File "/home/marija/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py", line 564, in merge_with
    (self, other))
ValueError: Shapes (64, 1, 40, 64) and (64, 2, 40, 64) are not compatible
```

Comment: you need to share your input sample data and  the code that you modified from the original linked examples. simple description is not enough масяня ))) also full traceback is needed with local variables, e.g. http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-xmode or https://github.com/skorokithakis/tbvaccine

Comment: Do you have a minimal reproducible example you can share?

Comment: The example input data, the code, and the error traceback are provided in the edit to the question as requested, please let me know if there is anything else that can help.

Comment: Does it maybe have to do with the fact that you are multiplying by 1 here.         h3, self.h3_w, self.h3_b = deconv2d(
            h2, [self.batch_size, s_h2, s_w2, self.gf_dim*1], name='g_h3', with_w=True) instead of 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your ops.py file

your problem come from the striding size in your deconv filter, modify the header for `conv2d` and `deconv2d` to:

```
def conv2d(input_, output_dim, 
       k_h=5, k_w=5, d_h=1, d_w=2, stddev=0.02,
       name="conv2d"):

def deconv2d(input_, output_shape,
       k_h=5, k_w=5, d_h=1, d_w=2, stddev=0.02,
       name="deconv2d", with_w=False):
```

Like this it started to train for me. I didn't check the output though.

The problem is considering the shape of your input, strinding on height by 2 (original value for d_h) will result by a `(64, 1, 40, 64)` shape during back propagation. (Because you only have 2 values)

Also you might think to change `k_h=5` to `k_h=2` as taking 5 element on height when you have only 2 doesn't make so much sense.

Comment: Thank you a lot - it started training for me, too.